# Calling a third party package's management command from a Django view

Tags: python, django, django-two-factor-auth

I am currently using the package 'django-two-factor-authentication' in my Django project and I see the management commands here (https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/1.14.0/management-commands.html)

My client would like to have a specific message for users who have not enabled two factor authentication.  How would I call this from a view to check their status?

I tried this already:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
authed = call_command('two_factor_status fake_email@gmail.com')
print('authed response')
print(authed)
```

but I get an error message saying that this is an unknown command.  If I leave the email out the page doesn't crash and I don't get an error but it prints out "None".

***Update
With this specific package you can check if the user has enabled two factor authentication with

```
request.user.is_verified
```

I would still like to know if there is a way to call management commands from a view when they are from a third party package though.

Comment: I think you should pass the package name to call_command( 'package_name', 'two_factor_status fake_email@gmail.com')  and then print the result from stdout as call_command return result on stdout.

Comment: I just get an error saying that 'two_factor' is an unknown command when I try this.

Comment: Please check if you can call the command from the command line

Comment: I have checked and it does work with
```
python manage.py two_factor_status fake_email@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the command and arguments. Please notice, that you will only get the value the `handle()` method of the command returns, if any, and not the output which will be printed if you execute the command.

```py
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('two_factor_status', 'fake_email@gmail.com')
```

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code

I would recommend not to call the command but use the logic directly in the view. This reduces the overhead and allows more granular handling of the response.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from two_factor.utils import default_device

def your_view(request):
    # ... your code
    user = User.objects.get_by_natural_key(username)
    if default_device(user):
        # 2FA enabled
    else:
        # 2FA not enabled
```

- https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth/blob/1.14.0/two_factor/management/commands/two_factor_status.py
- https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth/blob/1.14.0/two_factor/utils.py